# Modifying .git folder in a remote repo

Tags: git, git-config, gitattributes, assembla

I needed to retain the current file in the master branch while merging the other changes from the branch. I used the `.gitattributes` file to specify a driver which only merges `ours`. It all worked fine locally but when I tried to merge in the git provider it throwed a merge conflict. I can't find a way to set the driver in the hosted remote repository. Then I added a `.gitconfig` file which will store the merge settings and I updated the `.git/config` file to include the custom `.gitconfig`. file I included int the root of the repo.

My local config path looks like this:

```
[include]
path = ../.gitconfig
```

I need a way to replicate this in the remote repo. Is that even possible ?

Comment: How are the merges performed ? Do the users merge on their machine, then push ? or is the actual merge performed on some central machine ?

Comment: @LeGEC The merge is performed on the git provider, we use a service provider called assembla. We only push only our dev branch from local machine then the dev -> master is done in assembla

Comment: I'd ask the support team at Assembla. I don't know how their merges are actually performed on their servers.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the hosting platform for your remote is a managed service, I would ask technical support about your use case.

Depending on how "merging" is implemented on their platform (do they run the merge directly on the central repo, or on a clone ? do they use a stock `git` binary ? or some implementation on top of libgit ? jgit ? go-git ? ...) the elements to install or activate may be completely different than what you would have on your local machine.